# Inserting a special character at the proper place in a string using C#

Tags: c#, string

If I have a string like:

```
"SMITH 10-12 4-11H2"
```

And I want to modify this string to have a # after the first dash AND the following space to be like:

```
"SMITH 10-12 #4-11H2"
```

What is the best way to do this using C#?

Comment: How exactly are the rules for the input string? Is simply adding a # after the second space enough?

Comment: @svick- it would have to be after the first date range so yes that would be the rule it would need to follow.  sometimes a string may look like "SMITH SOMETEXT 5-12 8H55" so the best way I can describe is after the first "-" and Space.  "SMITH SOMETEXT 5-12 #8H55"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any checks it could look like this:

```
int pos1 = text.IndexOf('-');    
int pos2 = text.IndexOf(' ', pos1);    
string result = text.Insert(pos2+1, "#");
```